# Inserting .NET Double.MinValue into an Access "Double" field

Tags: .net, ms-access

I am trying to save some double values from my .NET project to MS Access using adodb.
If I have uninitialized values I want to save Double.MinValue as a default value into my access db.

The problem is that the range differs in .NET and in Access.
For .NET for example the minvalue is

> -1.79769313486232e308

and for MS Access the minvalue is

> -1.79769313486231E308

can anybody tell me why there is a difference because both are using 8 bytes ...
or is there any workaround for my problem. I want to make sure that my users are able to use the full range of Double. Because they won't know that they are "not allowed" to use Double.MinValue ...

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "[users] won't know that they are 'not allowed' to use Double.MinValue". Are you building some sort of component that other .NET developers can use?

Comment: I am bugfixing an AccessInterface for our own IDE. So yeah my "Users" are developers themeselves. The IDE is written in C#. The "Users" develop in VB.NET. So I have a class in C# which allow to add double values to an AccessTable. However if you use Double.MinValue the value is not saved because of mentioned behaviour.

Why does it matter? ofc I can convert the value inside my Interface but I want to understand why there is a difference ..

Comment: Re: "Why the discrepancy?" - @EricLippert might know (or might know somebody who knows), but I doubt that many people do. It's probably just an obscure implementation thing. Re: "Why does it matter?" - I asked because "regular" users of "regular" applications don't normally have access to `Double.MinValue` (or even know what it is). I really didn't see how it could be an issue unless you were building a component like you described.

Comment: hmm maybe stackoverflow is not the right place to ask the question. Maybe I should ask msdn staff. Probably there is no solution atm.

Comment: You're probably right on both counts. I seriously doubt that either VBA or .NET will be changed so that they "agree" on this particular point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Note that this original answer was based on the premise of the question that there WAS a discrepancy between the minimum Double values available in .NET and Access. As stated in the other answer from the question owner, that is actually not true.)*

My guess would be that the discrepancy is simply an obscure implementation detail. The VBA/VB6 code base is much older than the .NET code base and the people who built VBA/VB6 may have either

- hit a limitation of the environment (at the time) that prevented them from squeezing that last `0.00000000000001` of precision into the range, or
- had to make a compromise (e.g., for efficiency in computation, storage, or whatever) and the "price" of that compromise was that the `Double` range was reduced by that miniscule amount.

Software design sometimes involves trade-offs, so perhaps that last `0.00000000000001` was sacrificed for some other benefit. The true answer may be lost in the mists of time.

**Edit re: statement in other answer**

> It seems impossible to send Double.MinValue via sql statement to access.

Although it may not be possible to create a SQL statement with a string **literal** containing `Double.MinValue` by simply invoking `.ToString()` on it, this code definitely does work (tested with an Access 2010 database):

```csharp
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DoubleTest (DoubleField) VALUES (?)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Double.MinValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @SilvioMarcovic I have updated my answer re: saving `Double.MinValue` to an Access database via SQL.

Answer (score 4):

okay I checked it again and now I have to realize that I am at fault here.
The numbers posted above are wrong. For both its the value

```
-1.7976931348623157e308.
```

When I asked the question I viewed an untrustworthy source. The problem is that upon converting Double.MinValue to a string the resulting string is "-1.79769313486232e308" and converting it back to double results in an OverflowException.

You can test this with following snippet

```
double dblVal = Double.MinValue;
string strVal = dblVal.ToString();
dblVal = Convert.ToDouble(strVal);
```

Hence I am sending an sql query in order to store the value in access I am doing this transformation..

Next time I should check my sources better (: It seems impossible to send Double.MinValue via sql statement to access. I did a workaround in my AccessInterface.